# .htaccess redirection rule for site

Tags: .htaccess, url

I need help with htaccess URL rewriting for my site.

Problem is that just first page in some category has nice cruft free URL, and all other pages has dirty URLs.

For example first page has link like this:

```
http://www.my-site-name.com/Category-name/Subcategory-name/
```

But page 2, and any other pages are like this:

```
http://www.my-site-name.com/showcat.php?cat=Category-name&subcat=Subcategory-name&page=2
http://www.my-site-name.com/showcat.php?cat=Category-name&subcat=Subcategory-name&page=3
```

So, I need some SEO friendly htaccess redirect rule to make URLs like this:

```
http://www.my-site-name.com/Category-name/Subcategory-name-page-X/
```

or like this

```
http://www.my-site-name.com/Category-name/Subcategory-name/X/
```

But probably I would like first more.

**This is part of .htaccess for that: (I just added full content, maybe there is something more about it.**

```
## For top rated items
RewriteRule ^top/page/(.*)/$ top.php?page=$1 [L]

## For latest items
RewriteRule ^latest/recent-page-(.*)/$ latest.php?page=$1 [L]

## For show most rated - most clicked - most downloaded and most searched items
RewriteRule ^most-rated.html$ showmost.php?type=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^most-clicked.html$ showmost.php?type=2 [L]
RewriteRule ^most-downloaded.html$ showmost.php?type=3 [L]
RewriteRule ^most-Searched.html$ showmost.php?type=4 [L]

## For showing category of item
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ showcat.php?cat=$1 [L]

## For showing subcategory of item
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ showcat.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2 [L]

## For showig item
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html$ show.php?cat=$1&sub_cat=$2&img=$3&rewrite=true [L]

## this section should be inserted just after the showing item rule above
#if the query string has cat, sub_cat and Img
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=(.+)&sub_cat=(.+)&img=(.+)$ [NC]
#and it is for resource show.php, then 301 redirect to Keyword rich URL
RewriteRule ^show\.php$ http://www.my-site-name.com/%1/%2/%3.html? [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: I am novice here. Please tell me how I can accept correct answer, what I should do?

Comment: There is a gray check-mark left of the answers. Just click the one next to the question that answered your question (best).

Answer (score 2):

I also cleaned it up a little

```
#don't rewrite if file or dir exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [L]

## For showing category of item
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ showcat.php?cat=$1 [L]

## For showing paged subcategory of item
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)-page-([0-9]+)/$ showcat.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2&page=$3 [L]

## For showing subcategory of item
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ showcat.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2&page=1 [L]

## For showig item
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html$ show.php?cat=$1&sub_cat=$2&img=$3&rewrite=true [L]
```

Comment: @user1038179 what do you mean? The third rule should do what you wanted.

Comment: I just added full .htaccess code for my CMS, maybe it will tell you something more. I also tried your answer, but URLs are the same, I still do not have pretty URLs. I still have this: `http://www.my-site-name.com/showcat.php?cat=Category-name&subcat=Subcategory-name&page=2`